# How to serve the files produced using ng build

Tags: angular, server, production

I have production code, and when I condense the code using the command `ng build`. Am I suppose to serve up the files produced in the folder called "dist" myself?  If so, how and in which order. It was usually always done using `ng serve` but now it is my responsibility to serve up all the files, since where I am placing the files, I do not have angular.

Comment: Any web server can do that. You just need to put the content of `dist` somewhere where the webserver expects content it is supposed to server. Check the web server docs. You can use Apache, Nginx, IIS, ...

Comment: Yes you need a webserver to serve the content, which is normally index.html,  some js files and the assets.  There is not really an order, it's always the index.html file that is going to be served (You 'll need to configure the server to handle angular routes)